# Heads-up: Shoving pre-flop

Tags: texas-hold-em, all-in, pre-flop, heads-up, short-stack

Heads-up no-limit texas-holdem: You are the button with the SB. Both you and your opponent play perfect poker.

How deep (in BB) can your (or your opponent's) stack be, so that all-in or fold are your only viable options? What would be the range for all-in and for fold (possibly depending on depth)?

If you were deeper than that, how much would you lose by using an only all-in or fold strategy compared to the optimal strategy?